# Pause spring SqsListener to pull messages from queue

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, amazon-sqs, sqslistener

Currently I have a SQS queue that move the messages to a DLQ after 5 retries, I'm using spring `SqsListener` to read the queue:

```kotlin
@SqsListener(
    value = ["\${messaging.queue.orders}"],
    deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS
)
fun handleOrders(message: String) {
    // process order
}
```

Now I'm trying to use a feature toggle to pause the listener, but I could not find a way to do that, I tried to use the `Acknowledgment` manually, but the message is move to the DLQ if I don't send the success ack event:

```kotlin
@SqsListener(
    value = ["\${messaging.queue.orders}"],
    deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.NEVER
)
fun handleOrders(message: String, ack: Acknowledgment) {
    if(toggle.orders.enabled) {
        // process order
        ack.acknowledge()
    }
    // else don not process or ack the message
}
```

As I said, the problem with the solution above is that if I don't execute the `ack.acknowledge()` the message is moved to the DLQ after the fifth time, so I would need to pause/stop the `SqsListener` to pull messages from the Queue if the toggle is disabled, and start/resume if it's enabled again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar issue.

Googling it, I found [this](https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-cloud-aws/issues/523#issuecomment-637597632) issue on the archived predecessor of [spring-cloud-aws-sqs](https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws/blob/main/spring-cloud-aws-sqs/src/main/java/io/awspring/cloud/sqs/annotation/SqsListener.java#L28).

It describes **this workaround**:

1. Get the beans of the listener container that wraps the SQS listener (from the SpringBoot application context)
2. Call the `stop()` method on them

Nowadays in [spring-cloud-aws](https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws),  [@SqsListener](https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws/blob/main/spring-cloud-aws-sqs/src/main/java/io/awspring/cloud/sqs/annotation/SqsListener.java#L28) is still there.

The listener container class you may want to autowire is `io.awspring.cloud.sqs.listener.SqsMessageListenerContainer` (to call its inherited `io.awspring.cloud.sqs.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer#stop`).

Answer (score -1):

You can toggle creation of SqsListener using `@ConditionalOnExpression`

Like:

```
@SqsListener(
    value = ["\${messaging.queue.orders}"],
    deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.NEVER
)
@ConditionalOnExpression("\${toggle.orders.enabled:false}")
fun handleOrders(message: String) {
    // process order
}
```

And adding following to `application.yaml`

```
toggle:
  orders:
    enabled: true
```

if you change the property, you will have to restart the server unless you are using spring cloud for configuration

You can also use `@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "toggle", name = "orders.enabled")`

Comment: It did't work. Looks like those annotations works only with Beans, which is not this case.

Comment: You can try adding the `@ConditionalOnExpression("\${toggle.orders.enabled:false}")` onto the `@Component/Service` class which contains the `hanldeOrders` method.